# Joining and matching tables in SQL with query

Tags: sql, oracle

So im trying to select multiple tables and do a comparison between
starNumb, mvNumb from Star table and Movie table, if the two match I then want it to return / display the starName along with a total count of how many times that StarName is related to mvNumb if that makes sense.

So far I have this and it's not playing ball, I'm sure this is something very simple but struggling.

```
SELECT STARNUMB.STAR, MVNUMB.MOVIE
FROM MOVIES JOIN STAR
where STARNUMB = MVNUMB;
```

What I want from this is something that looks like this below as an output.

Column1
StarName = TestName1

Column2
MovNumb = 1

Meaning that star has appeared in the movie 1 x time.

The tables and FD's look something like this:

Bold = Primary keys

- Star(**starNumb**, starName, brthPlce, starBorn, starDied)
- MovStar(mvNumb*, starNumb*).   <-----  foreign keys
- Movie(**mvNumb**, mvTitle, yrMde, mvType, crit, mpaa, noms, awrd, dirNumb*)
- Borrow(**txNumb**, mvNumb*, borDte, mmbNumb*)
- Member(**mmbNumb**, mmbName, mmbAddr, mmbCty, mmbSt, numRent, bonus, joinDate)
- Director(**dirNumb**, dirName, dirBorn, dirDied)**

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result ..

Comment: Why you want to match star number and movie number is there any relationship

Comment: You need to add `MovStar` to your join: Star - MovStar - Movie

Comment: No, your question does not make sense.  Sample data in a text table would really help clarify the first paragraph.

Comment: Th point to this is to list the name of each star which starred in a movie and the total number of movies that each star has starred in a descending order. It's for an assignment and according to the lecturer there should be 27 lines in the query. I don't have any sample data.

Comment: *"the lecturer there should be 27 lines in the query"* Really? I'd be fascinated to see how your teacher manages to pad this out to 27 lines. It's unlikely a correct solution will even reach 27 **words**.

Answer (score 1):

There's an *n-to-m* relation between stars and movies which results in a bridging table `MovStar`, you need to add this to the join. But as long as you only want to count the number of movies per star you need to join only `Movies` and `MovStar`:

```
SELECT m.starName, count(*)
FROM MOVIES m JOIN MovStar ms
  on m.STARNUMB = ms.starNumb
group by m.starName
order by 2 desc
```